# Netbeans is not running project. Showing error Could not connect to admin Listener for Glass Fish Server 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I just installed netbeans 7.2 and made a project in it. But when i tried to run the project . I got the following error

[image]

The error is

```
Could not connect to admin Listener for Glass Fish server 3.1.2
Verify that Netbeans can make outbound connections to localhost:4848
```

I also uncheck the `Use IDEs Proxy Settings` by going to properties of glass fish but it still isn't working. Any idea why i am getting this ?

The error occurring at line

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

Thank you.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edit**

There is file server.txt in the directory you mentioned. This is what the file contains.

```
Sep 24, 2012 1:18:39 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:C:/Program Files/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
       -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06/jre/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
Sep 24, 2012 1:18:39 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 0 msec.
```

Comment: Can you connect to localhost:4848 from your browser?

Comment: no. Even if i try to run the glass fish from console, then it fails with error code -1. Is this windows xp issue ?  I am running it on windows XP.

Comment: So Glassfish is not running at all? Check the server log during start-up to find out why the start fails.

Comment: How can i check server log ? when i run the command from console then i get message `The server exited prematurely with exit code -1, 073, 741, 819.`

Comment: You should find it in `glassfish-install-dir\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log` (if you use the default installation with `domain1` as domain name)

Comment: There's nothing special in the file... i mean no error. I am editing my post. You can look there.

Comment: done. You can check the edit now

Comment: Not sure, but from the log file it seems that no domain is started. Did you configure a domain for your server? Does it respond to localhost:8080?

Comment: no localhost:8080 is also not working...

Comment: It seems that the domain was not configured correctly during glassfish installation. You could either re-install glassfish or try to add a new domain to your existing installation.

Comment: i installed glassfish with the netbeans 7.2. How can i add new domain to my glass-fish ?